# how to return multiple values from get function in c++

Tags: c++, function, class, get, return

I am basically passing two parameters in the private class and I am trying to access these two parameters in my main function. Since I made those two parameters private, I am using get and set functions to access these parameters, but I am not able to return two values from the get function. Please help me.  The last post that asked kind of same question, but this time it has been asked for object oriented concept.

```
class FirstClass{
  public:
    void setName(int x,int y){
        a = x;
        b = y;
}
    int getName(){
    return a,b;

     }
  private:
    int a,b;
};
```

Comment: you need to use two functions to get two return values in this case.

Comment: Or return a struct containing both values.  Or pass in variables by reference and copying into those variables.

Comment: Note: `a,b` is the comma operator, which doesn't act anything like in Python.

Comment: @chris: ... and please don't overload the comma-operator to do something similar as in Python :D

Comment: @tgmath, Too late: `someContainer = 1,3,5,4,7;` Anyway for something like this, it's already in the language somewhat: `auto foo() {return std::make_tuple(1, 3, "abc");}` At least that will be standard in a few months.

Comment: Return a tuple and use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie to store the result

Answer (score 2):

Either use references:

```
int getName(int &a1, int &b1) {
    a1 = a;
    b1 = b;
}
```

or use two functions:

```
int getA() {
    return a;
}

int getB() {
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Think you meant to say references.

Answer (score 0):

accessors/mutators or getters/setters  are intended to get/set only one value. Your code should be like this:

```
class FirstClass{
  public:
  FirstClass(int x,int y){ //constructor, initialize the values
    a = x;
    b = y;
}
  int getA(){
  return a;
 }

  int getB(){
  return b;
 }

  int setA(const int newVal){ //using const is a good practice
   a=newVal;
 }

  int setB(const int newVal){ //using const is a good practice
   b= newVal;
 }

 // you can use reference/pointer to *obtain* multiple values, although it is rarely used and seems inappropriate in your code
 void getBoth(int& aRef, int& bRef){
   aRef = a;
   bRef = b;
}


  private:
  int a,b;
};
```

Comment: so basically i have to create seprate get and set function for teach parameter??

Comment: @user3711379, yes. use constructor for initialization of all, and get/set for access and reset individual values.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a single value or take parameters as value-result arguments ( pointers or references) or return structure with parameters packed. Most probably you will need to access just `a` or just `b` separately after all, so why not to just create two accessors

```
int getNameA(){
  return a;
}

int getNameB(){
  return b;
}
```